# How can I split text on punctuation but not on emails or other expressions?

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I want split text on punctuation but not on emails - consider that unicode must be used since not all people speaks English.

```
import re

example = 'My email is John@gmail.com. My name is John. Her email is Anna@gmail.com'
print re.split('[.]\s*', example, re.UNICODE)
# gives ['My email is John@gmail', 'com', 'My name is John', 'Her email is Anna@gmail', 'com']
# required ['My email is John@gmail.com', 'My name is John', 'Her email is Anna@gmail.com']
```

How to separate it correctly - I know regex but have not idea how to solve - I think that [look behind](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) will not work since number of characters is not fixed.

I can write concurrent matching first email that separator and consider that email always wins separator.

---

Consider that **humans are imperfect** and it is natural language so example can be - we should help with their simple mistakes but not all:

```
'My email is john@www.mysite.pl.I am teenager.'
'My email is john@www.mysite.pl. I am teenager.'
```

[Top level domains ends](http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt) can be learned and save in some dictionary like '.com|.pl|...'.

Comment: do you have some data you can test this stuff with? I don't think you can get a solution that will cover all possible problems here... but surly you can cover most of the cases with the top lvl domains after @, and the space after the '.' rules and flag misfits for review and iterate from there.

Comment: I have enough data for test (whole internet). As I said before and you there will be not solution solving all problems but I want solve the most not the basic one - assume that there is only `.com` top domain this enough to find solution.

Comment: This is not an easy problem to solve, and I guarantee you can not reliably split *only* on punctuation using just regular expressions. You will need to do some more advanced natural language processing to do some pre-splitting tokenization.

Comment: @JoelCornett I want solve this problem first.

Answer (score 1):

To your immediate problem, did you notice this solves it:

```
re.split('[.]\s+'
```

Besides that, people do several things:

1. Stop-patterns, dictionaries, things like dr. et.al. a.k.a. you can check an example [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/gate/code/HEAD/tree/gate/trunk/plugins/ANNIE/resources/regex-splitter/non-split-patterns.txt).
2. Machine learning algorithms. They detect all potential sentence ends, like . ! ? etc. and run classification to guess which one is a sentence end. See [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) for example in python.

Comment: You are right next step is shortcuts (it should be not called stop patterns). NLTK is ok but too fat for simple sentences separation and is not designed for much more complex languages than English - see word 'do/done' no such form in English http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zrobi%C4%87  and simple 'do' which is in English: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/robi%C4%87 - it is different words/meaning but in English is only 'do' this is not translatable easily - Polish need complex inflexion at least 160 different inflection for objective only.

Answer (score 1):

Its not so easy, but for provided example its possible with negative lookahead:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> print re.split('\.(?!com)', example, re.UNICODE)
['My email is John@gmail.com', ' My name is John', ' Her email is Anna@gmail.com']
```

> assume that there is only .com top domain this enough to find solution.

**UPDATE**

Another example with one fail on `john@www.mysite.pl.I`, but you wrote:

> we should help with their simple mistakes but not all...

```
example = [
    'Hello John.Doe@gmail.com, Jane.Doe@mail.edu.pl and Anna_Karenina@mail.gov.pl',
    'My email is john@www.mysite.pl.I am teenager.',
    'My email is john@www.mysite.pl. I am teenager.']

for sentence in example:
    for token in re.split('[.,](?![\w.]+)', sentence, re.UNICODE):
        for word in filter(None, token.split(' ')):
            print word

>>> example = [
...     'Hello John.Doe@gmail.com, Jane.Doe@mail.edu.pl and Anna_Karenina@mail.gov.pl',
...     'My email is john@www.mysite.pl.I am teenager.',
...     'My email is john@www.mysite.pl. I am teenager.']
>>>
>>> for sentence in example:
...     for token in re.split('[.,](?![\w.]+)', sentence, re.UNICODE):
...         for word in filter(None, token.split(' ')):
...             print word
...
Hello
John.Doe@gmail.com
Jane.Doe@mail.edu.pl
and
Anna_Karenina@mail.gov.pl
My
email
is
john@www.mysite.pl.I
am
teenager
My
email
is
john@www.mysite.pl
I
am
teenager
```

;))))

Comment: I will do concurrent matches to mark patterns like email than punctuation if punctuation will be in pattern like email I will skip splits on them - it make great change I think. Simple match of `.com` is not sufficient but thank for you help.

Comment: @Chameleon Ok, btw I added a new example and one more time with one assumption :(

Comment: Looks much better it trying now bisect + finditer - 1st phase it to learn exception than second phase to split if no exception.

Answer (score 1):

A common way to do this in Java and C is by using ICU library, which provides a mechanism called Break Iterator that can be configured by a file of regular expressions to recognize any number of regular patterns in text that you want to consider whole tokens (emails, numbers, phone numbers, etc.)

There is a Python version as I can see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyICU

It is also THE library one should use to deal with Unicode text.

Comment: Looks like the best idea.

Comment: Ok, then to save you the time, the thing is called RuleBasedBreakIterator. It is constructed from a text file of definitions (a long string, actually). It contains a number of regexp definition first, lines like $Whitespace = [[:Zs:] [:Zl:]]; or $Letters = [:L:]+; defining respective regexps, and token definition lines at the end using them, like $Letters {200};  (meaning "see a sequence from current point that matches $Letters, select it as a token and give it a type "200"). Add a .; at the very end to consume at least one character in any case, or it might stop going forward at some point.

Comment: You can also comment lines with #, define ranges $CJK = [\u4e00-\u9fff];  and lists $Digits=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]; and obviously construct definitions on top of definitions $Cap = [:Lu:]|[:Lt:];
$Low = [:Ll:];
$Capitalized = $Cap $Low+;